# Multiple linear regression for a surface using NumPy - example

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

This question is close to: [fitting a linear surface with numpy least squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617985/fitting-a-linear-surface-with-numpy-least-squares), but there's no sample data. I must be terribly slow but it seems I can't get it to work.

I have the following code:

```
    import numpy as np
    XYZ = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]])
    A = np.row_stack((np.ones(len(XYZ[0])), XYZ[0, :], XYZ[1:]))
    coeffs = np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, XYZ[2, :])[0]
    print coeffs
```

The output is:

```
    [  5.00000000e-01   5.55111512e-17   9.71445147e-17   5.00000000e-01]
```

I want `z = a + bx + cy`, i.e. three coefficients, but the output gives me four. Where do I go wrong here? I expected coeffs to be something like:

```
    [ 1.0 0.0 0.0]
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have no np here to try but maybe a typo in `XYZ[1:]` instead of `XYZ[1,:]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Schneider (comment) is right: you'll want to feed `XYZ[1, :]` to `row_stack`:

```
>>> A = np.row_stack((np.ones(len(XYZ[0])), XYZ[0, :], XYZ[1, :]))
>>> np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, XYZ[2, :])[0]
array([  1.00000000e+00,  -7.85046229e-17,  -7.85046229e-17])
```