# Numpy or Scipy way to do polynomial fitting in 2 dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data that looks like this

[image: Data]

What is the typical way to do a polynomial map of z based on x and y?  I have used numpy.polyfit in the past to do similar things in 2 dimensions, so I suppose I could just iterate through all the points and then fit those answers with another 1d polyfit.  However, it seems there should be a more straight forward way.

By the way the picture shows 2 different sets of data that would be fit with different equations.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997152/python-3d-polynomial-surface-fit-order-dependent

Comment: I saw this, but it seems a very custom solution.  I am looking into it now but haven't gotten it to work out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that what you really want is to fit a surface ([linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617985/fitting-a-linear-surface-with-numpy-least-squares) or [spline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html)) in terms of z(x,y), but you have only one single line of data. This is like solving for two unknowns with only one equation - the problem is, basically, how could you decide if the difference in your red line from A to B was caused by the change in PSI, or the change in V?
My suggestions:

- fit a surface to your existing dataset. You will get something.
- try to get more data that you can fit a more accurate surface on
- do what you first wanted - fit a function separately in each dimensions, combine them and use the best of the three functions (the one fitted for PSI, the one fitted for V and the one combined).
- try to combine your PSI and V factors with some fancy physics-based trick into one significant factor that contains both of them

Comment: I think you are right that I want to fit a surface.  I have some more data at different pressures and the same voltages.  Let me toy around with it some so I can be sure this is the correct answer.

Comment: While you were right that I wanted to fit a surface, I believe what I was looking for was linear regression instead of a spline.  The spline will fit it, but is a bit more complicated to implement on low level hardware as a linearization.  Linear regression could also be used to fit the original curve that I asked to fit, so I think that would have been the most correct answer